# Simplest way to keep and increment an ID number in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a function for actions-on-google to run in firebase functions. At one point in the function I need to access the last ID number used (in int form), increment it, use the new ID, then store the last used ID for any other subsequent function.

It seems using the firestore database would work for this, but it seems overkill to use a whole database instance just for a single variable, is there a better, more recommended or just simpler way to achieve this 'global' variable between all instances of my function within the firebase ecosystem? Or should I just use firestore?

Comment: well you need what you need, at the end, storing something needs a database, either reuse one of your web services to store it or use a service like firestore. I don't think it's something bad.

Comment: Firestore seems to be the only way out to me.But if I am not wrong it might also cause the lost update problem with the variable. If two requests are coming almost simultaneously both might read the same value and so update of one of the requests will be lost.

Comment: You'll use a transaction for that. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions